# PDO connection in Strato

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, server

I am a bit new when creating and managing web servers, and I am having problems trying to configure my website in Strato (a web hosting service).
I have used other hosts in the past, and most of them in the same way, so the code should not change much.
However, with this host, I cannot connect to the database. They do not offer much help about it in the faqs, so I thought to ask you whilst I wait for their reply.

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong in the following code:

```
<?php

   $dsn = 'mysql:host=rdbms.strato.de;dbname=DB2613867';
   $username = 'U******';
   $password = '*******';

   try {
       $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   // more code
?>
```

It throws an internal server error.

PS: the way they offer to connect to the database is without PDO.

Thank you!

> I have checked the username, password and database name, and they are all correct as far as I know

Comment: What does the error log show? Either their documentation is realllly old or their systems are reallly old. `From EasyWeb packages upwards you can use PHP versions 3 and 4.1, as well as the new versions 4.4.1 and 5. ` http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/article/567/This-is-how-you-use-the-MySQL-Database.html

Comment: You should contact their support and ask, if they don't support PDO than you should search another service (I've used https://www.cleardb.com and it worked great with PDO)

Comment: @chris85 It takes a long time before it ends in a **500 Internal Server Error page** with:  _"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"_ 
I have read their documentation, it seems quite old, although they use the last versions of PHP and MySQL

Comment: @AlonEitan I have sent a message to their support, but I was hoping to do more coding tonight, and leave the page working. They won't reply anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

The support contacted me apologizing they hadn't been able to upload my database details yet, so it was actually giving me an error because it did not recognise the DB (after almost two days...). It is now fixed and running.

Thanks for the help anyway!